# Azure Resource Manager set static IP using json template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Using Azure Resource Manager Json template, can we set internal static IP without having to assign IP? My template creates a couple of Vms. When I set privateIPAllocationMethod to Static I get error that I have to set the IP also. Is it possible to assign IP dynamically and set it static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or are you looking for something you can do in ARM after you get an IP from Azure using dynamic the switch to static.

```html
{     
    "name": "SetStaticIP",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat(parameters('envPrefix'),parameters('vmName'),'nic')]",
        "[concat(parameters('envPrefix'),parameters('vmName'))]",
        "Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/SetStaticIP.json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "VirtualNetwork": {
                "value": "[parameters('VirtualNetwork')]"
            },
            "VirtualNetworkId": {
                "value": "[parameters('VirtualNetworkId')]"             },
                        "nicName": {
                            "value": "[concat(parameters('envPrefix'),parameters('vmName'),'nic')]"
                        },
                        "ipAddress": {
                            "value": "[reference(concat(parameters('envPrefix'),parameters('vmName'),'nic')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]" 
                        }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Please revise this by expanding on your answer. It is unclear whether it is an actual answer, a suggestion or a question.

Answer (score 0):

YES you can change dynamically assigned IP to static. Try this-

```
$nic=Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name "TestNIC" -ResourceGroupName "TestRG"
$nic.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAllocationMethod = "Static"
$nic.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAddress = "x.x.x.x"
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```

You can refer to this article- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-arm-ps/

Thanks.